# Sampling with distrubutional screw / shift?

Tags: r

I generate a list of binary numbers and put it in a data.frame before generating 10 lists as extra columns that contain the 10 numbers in different orders:

```
n = 10
docs = data.frame(data=sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2)))
docs$data = factor(docs$data)
levels(docs$data) = c("NR", "R")
# debug graph
plot(docs$data)

for (i in 2:10) {
  docs[,i] = sample(docs$data, length(docs$data), replace = FALSE)
}
```

How can I can apply a distribution to this sampling so that I can influence the likelihood of 1's appearing at beginning of the ranked list rather than the end)?

Comment: Sample has a `prob=` argument which allows you to specify "weights" for choosing each value (see description in the Details section of `?sample`). It probably would be better to describe the exact distribution you are after.

Comment: this prob feature is hardly explained in the package documentation. Is there a standard interface to its parameter? Can you point me to some examples? I currently only have the example above where i use prob=c(0.8, 0.2) to distribute fix between two variables...